# Correct usage of thinking about future

Tags: future

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> I had to ponder on my future at a beautiful place.

Comment: The grammar is fine. The semantics (meaning) are a bit strange. Was your future at a beautiful pace, or your pondering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is acceptable. But  according to  Collins Dictionary: ponder
verb
(when intransitive, 
sometimes followed by ON or OVER) 
to give thorough or deep consideration (TO); meditate (UPON). 
The thing is that this verb is usually transitive and is followed by the direct object without any preposition /for  example: to ponder future.../.

Comment: Thank you! Does "at a beautiful place" make sense in the context?

Comment: The adverbial modifier is of no importance here.